# Any pointers on beamer with LaTeXML?

Tags: beamer, latexml

I'm looking for ways to translate presentations, handouts or the result of `article` + `beamerarticle` to HTML. Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

We have an open issue on the topic at [the LaTeXML issue tracker](https://github.com/brucemiller/LaTeXML/issues/231) to which you could add a +1 comment to, so that we keep track of interest, and so that you get notifications for any progress in that direction.

One thing that isn't obvious, which needs to be decided: Which HTML presentation framework should we use for the resulting slides? A decision that should likely be based on which existing ones are best aligned with beamer's approach to overlays and transitions. We could of course offer support for several different HTML dialects, but we need to start with at least one.